# Matrix of pointers to floats in python

Tags: python

Consider a list `L` of floats. I want to create a matrix `M` such as some of its elements are floats from the list.

My problem is that members of `L` can change and I want the element `M[i][j]` to always be the float `L[n]`.

Is there a pythonic way to make `M[i][j]` point to `L[n]` and always be `L[n]` even if `L[n]` changes?

Comment: `float` is immutable

Comment: So wait, do you want `M[i][j]` to change *with* `L[n]` or to keep the original value even after `L[n]` changes?

Comment: you could use `numpy` [views](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html)

Comment: @TimPietzecker to change with `L[n]`. Sorry if I wasn't clear

Comment: How did you envision forming your matrix from the list `L`? Straight 2D projection (i.e. `M[0][0] -> L[0]; M[0][1] -> L[1]; M[1][0] -> L[2];` etc.) or?

Comment: @zwer it's more complicated than that. I found a non-elegant solution to my particular problem. However I would like to know if there is a general way to do what I ask...

Comment: Well, explain then how do you need to map your matrix `M` to your list `L`? We cannot help you if we don't know what is your exact problem.

Comment: @zwer I'm simulating the growth of a coral. The coral lives in a "2D tank" where ressources diffuse. The tank is meshed with squares. Each of these squares is an element of a matrix. I have two matrices one containing the info of the amount of ressources in each square, another containing the info of which branch takes the case's ressources (each case can be used only by the branch who got there first). Coral branches are identified by its index (stocked in `L`), but indexes change during growth (when branches are added or removed), then `M` has to change with `L`.Is it clearer?